# Drupal link inside bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: theming

I inserted this with a new created Text format

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
   <a href="#" target="_blank" class="thumbnail">
      <img alt="test" src="#" />
     <h3>test</h3>
     <div class="mail"><a href="mailto:test@test.ch">E-mail</a></div>
   </a>
</div>
```

but drupal outputs this when i save the content

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
   <a class="thumbnail" target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="#" alt="#">
     <h3>Test</h3>
   </a>
<div class="mail"><a class="thumbnail" target="_blank" href="#"></a><a href="#">E-mail</a></div>
</div>
```

I want that the div mail is inside the anchor thumbnail but drupal strips out the anchor automaticly out of the anchour thumbnail.

Can anybody tell me how i can fix that?

Comment: Have you selected Full HTML text Format or  your Text Format must allow links etc, check you format and can compare with full format

Comment: yes i selected full html.

I also created a text format named "block html" and disable all filters so that is same like full html. But Full HTML and Block html don't work. I also tried to output is as php code but drupal also rewrite the output too

Comment: Nested `<a>` elements (anchor tags) are [forbidden in HTML syntax][1]. 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `<a>` elements (anchor tags) are [forbidden in HTML syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag).

Nested links are [illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) by w3.org rules.